# Animating a Core Plot ScatterGraph

Tags: ios, animation, core-animation, core-plot, scatter-plot

I have a scatter Graph in my iPad app using Core Plot, and all is working well. What I want to do is animate the drawing of the line so that it looks like each point to point on the graph is being drawn in front of the user. I'm not looking to fade the line in as I have already got this working.

I have seen the question asked below which is very similar, but I don't fully understand the answer.
[Core-Plot - animating a CPScatterPlot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411431/core-plot-animating-a-cpscatterplot)

Please bare in mind I am new to Core Plot and have only been using it for a day or so.

Thanks

Comment: How did you manage to fade the single "chunk" of the line?

Answer (score 3):

```
self.plot.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0); // Moved anchor point, 

CABasicAnimation *scaling = [CABasicAnimation 
                                 animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale.y"]; // s
scaling.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0]; 
scaling.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0]; 
scaling.duration = 0.1f; // Duration 
scaling.removedOnCompletion = NO; 
scaling.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards; 
[self.plot addAnimation:scaling forKey:@"scaling"];
```

Comment: With that duration value the animation might be to fast to see. Increase the value if that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the "real time demo" plot in the Plot Gallery example app included with Core Plot. It uses a timer to add points to a scatter plot one at a time. The code can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/source/browse/examples/CorePlotGallery/src/plots/RealTimePlot.m).

The `-newData:` method adds a point to the plot and updates the plot range so the new point will be visible. The call to `-insertDataAtIndex:numberOfRecords:` causes the plot to retrieve the new data point and redraw automatically.

Comment: That doesn't seem to compile for some reason